# Nvidia: Windows kernel mode driver stopped responding and has successfully recovered

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Sometimes it gives me pop-up message (NVIDIA windows kernel mode driver stopped responding and has successfully recovered), and some times not.

Then I have to restart my computer. Because I cannot click on anything and display is in lower resolution with some green lines.

I have tried to roll back driver, to uninstal it even with some tool  http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/downloads.html

I am using: 
Driver 340.52, NVidia GeForce 8600M GS
Windows 7 ultimate

Any ideas?

Comment: common issue in gaming - http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2665946

Comment: tried "fix it" but still same

Comment: Related (still no fix though): https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/709328/geforce-drivers/nvidia-windows-kernel-mode-driver-335-23-stopped-responding-and-was-recovered-successfully/